# Bootstrap input group not grouping properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use an input group that I've modified from the bootstrap site.

This is what I have

[image: Current design]

This is what I want

[image: Wanted design]

This is my code

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" aria-label="Text input with segmented button dropdown" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What have I done wrong? Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r7ttxr6p/3/

Comment: Can you create a codepen that repeats probelm?

Comment: seems to be working ok http://jsfiddle.net/L7df2mud/ - could you have other code interfering with it?

Comment: Well, that's not okay. Because the dropdown button still has border-radius on the right side. As I can see in bootstrap css, there is no code for your case, you have to edit it with css to remove border-radius.

Comment: I' don't see the problem, the fiddle is ok, tested in chrome,opera, mozz, explorer, higher versions...

Comment: @eugensunic look closely at the corners of the dropdown, they are rounded and the button does not look like it is a part of the drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap has no css for that. Put this in your css:

```
.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn:not(:last-child).dropdown-toggle {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ubdoyn6z/1/

Comment: or you can switch places for `caret` and `button`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you enjoy this. It was stupidly annoying to figure out. The docs are not the best on this type of markup. 
https://jsbin.com/zabocusiti/edit?html,output

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented button dropdown" type="text"/>

  <div class="input-group-btn">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" >
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>

  </div>

</div><!-- /.input-group -->
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented button dropdown">
      <div class="input-group-btn">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zz1k5t3u/

Comment: Did you do anything? It looks like the problem is still there.

Comment: In my fiddle it looks ok. ??